# Ubuntu 17.04: Cannot access/see BIOS

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, bios, secure-boot

My system: GAZ97X-UD5H, 770 GTX, 32 GB, Ubuntu 17.04 currently testing Gnome Desktop (since Unity will be gone soon).

Yesterday, I ran a `sudo apt update` and there were like 10 packages to update. I checked briefly and as usual I saw a bunch of things with among them the papirus icon theme (quite active lately) and some other stuff I don't remember unfortunately (maybe grub I'm not sure).

At some point, some app or library or whatever I was updating, asked me something about Secure Boot, disabling or leaving it on (not quite sure).
There was lot of noise in my room so I wasn't focused on what I was doing...
Anyway, it also asked me for a password which I typed in.
Everything went fine.
Then after a while I thought I might check what's going on with the secure boot in the bios (couldn't remember if I had installed Ubuntu with the SB on or off and that last event made me wonder if it was still on or off).
I restarted the computer and could see the Gigabyte screen. Pressed <kbd>Del</kbd> to access the BIOS. Saw the weird mouse cursor (low rez) on a black screen then the cursor vanished and nothing. It's like I was accessing the BIOS without seing it.
I can use grub to access both W10 and Ubuntu. Both work well. But I cannot access or 'see' the BIOS. It looks like I can kinda access it without seeing it. And since I'm stuck on a blank screen I need to press the reset button to restart.

It's really weird. Haven't checked yet what apps I have installed yesterday, I believe there's a log somewhere.

Anyway meanwhile if someone has some suggestion or idea, that would be nice.

Thanks

Eric

P.S. The list of apps I updated yesterday:

shim-signed
papirus-icon-theme
grub-efi-amd64-bin
grub-common
grub2-common
libwhoopsie0:amd64
grub-efi-amd64-signed
grub-efi-amd64
whoopsie

Comment: if you can go to Ubuntu, run the command `grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log` and paste it to http://paste.ubuntu.com, then give us the link, that would be great.

Comment: Here you go: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25196889/

Comment: Try installing `nvidia-381`? That seems unlikely but it could be the issue.

Comment: I can try but I don't get it. How some nvidia driver could mess with the bios or the screen when the system is not even loaded?

Comment: Me neither TBH!

Comment: Sounds like your monitor does not support the video mode of your bios?

Comment: Well that would be some news, I have been using that monitor for quite a while now (like 3 years). Never had any problem to access the BIOS. It's a Dell U2414H and AFAIK Bios use low rez.

Comment: Ok I think I'm getting somewhere. I'm installing nvidia-381. I ran into the very same message about Secure Boot AND an error message from Sophos AV (which I installed mostly to check windows files): http://picpaste.com/Capture_d____cran_de_2017-07-29_14-05-26-bY54fm9x.png

Comment: I'm going to disable Sophos and see what happens.

Comment: If you install a proprietary driver like nVidia or Wireless then you have to have Secure boot off. The driver becomes part of boot/kernel and then is not allowed to be signed by Ubuntu as it is a binary blob which Ubuntu cannot review. If you have fast boot on in UEFI, you in effect have no time to press key to get into UEFI. You can from Windows and last entry in grub menu or "System Setup"

Comment: It's getting weirder by the minute even if I understand the Secure Boot is somehow the problem. Here is what I got at restart after installing nvidia-381 and disabling Sophos: http://picpaste.com/IMG_20170729_143334-Jp1VFcd7.jpg (and I could not enter the password I was asked before rebooting during install)

Answer (score 1):

On many (but not all) UEFI-based computers, the following command will reboot into the firmware setup utility from recent versions of Ubuntu:

```
sudo systemctl reboot --firmware
```

Given the symptoms you've reported, that might or might not actually help you, though; it could be that the firmware itself is messed up. If so, you might have trouble recovering. Ordinarily, when the firmware misbehaves, it at least works well enough for you to get in and reset it to its default settings, or to load a fresh firmware image. In your case, though, if the firmware is malfunctioning badly enough to not let you get in, your only hope may be to flash a new firmware image from Windows or Ubuntu. (The former is more likely to be supported.) You can check your computer/motherboard manufacturer's (Gigabyte's?) Web site to see if there's an update available for you to apply.

Note that some boot managers provide functionality similar to the `systemctl` command noted above, too. GRUB 2, rEFInd, and (IIRC) gummiboot/systemd-boot all provide this functionality; however, it might or might not be enabled on any given configuration. I think that GRUB 2 *should* enable it by default whenever possible, but I'm not positive of that. I haven't studied the configuration scripts or tried it on enough systems to know precisely when this feature will be available. If it is available, it should appear as a regular menu option. In rEFInd, it will show up as a tool (2nd-row icon) option if the firmware supports the feature and if you haven't changed the `showtools` line in `refind.conf` from the default.

Comment: On my `systemctl` help menu it shows `--firmware-setup` and not `--firmware` as the parameter to use.

Comment: I believe that either will work. I tried with `--firmware` before posting and it worked for me.

Comment: You are so right. Both `$ sudo systemctl reboot --firmware` and `--firmware-setup` return the same error on my CSM BIOS system: `Cannot indicate to EFI to boot into setup mode: Operation not supported`